# PHP key => value array to method arguments (order?)

Tags: php, arrays, methods, arguments

**I think this is quite interesting!!! :).**

---

**What I've got?**

In the application that I'm using on some level in some objects (doesn't really matter) I get an array, for example:

```
$array = array(
    'argument_label' => 'value_label',
    'argument_name' => 'value_name',
    'argument_id' => 'value_id'
)
```

I don't have any impact on how and when this array is created. Next, I've got a method:

```
public function arrayArgument($array) {
    $label = isset($array['argument_label']) ? $array['argument_label'] : 'default_label';
    $name = isset($array['argument_name']) ? $array['argument_name'] : 'default_name';
    $id = isset($array['argument_id']) ? $array['argument_id'] : 'default_id';

    // Do something
    return 'something';
}
```

I really hate it. There is no way of proper documentation for the method arguments (as PHPDocumentator work not so well with arrays), and those issets are driving me crazy. Additionally it is a nightmare for someone who will work with this code in the future, when I will already be a "retired nerd".

---

**What I want?**

I want to have a function like that:

```
public function notArrayArgument(
    $id='default_id', 
    $label='default_label', 
    $name='default_name'
) {
    // Do something
    return 'something';
}
```

---

**What I can do?**

When I get array, I can change some code, and make my own method run. So I need some kind of solution to get from here:

```
$array = array(
    'argument_label' => 'value_label',
    'argument_name' => 'value_name',
    'argument_id' => 'value_id'
)
```

To here:

```
notArrayArgument('value_id', 'value_label', 'value_name');
```

Or here:

```
notArrayArgument($array['argument_id'], $array['argument_label'], $array['argument_name']);
```

---

**What are the problems?**

1. This is not template like. The number of variables is always different, the names are always different, and sometimes some of them are passed, sometimes not.
2. It should work really fast...
3. Calling the method arguments in the right order. Array can be sorted, not sorted or random sorted, while the arguments inside method are always in the same order. The array should be reordered to match the method arguments order, and after that the method should be called.

---

**What I came with?**

1. I've got an idea using **reflectionClass**. I can check the names of method arguments, get them in order, reorder the array and try to call this method. But this is quite resource eating solution, as reflectionClass is not so fast I think.
2. Solution using **extract**? This would be great. But after extract, I need to use exact variables names in code. And I don't know them as every time they are different, and I need an universal approach.
3. NEW (thx to comment): call_user_func_array(). It is great, but it only works with indexed arrays, so this will be the last but not least step of the possible solution. As the order of arguments is still unknown...

**Does this problem have a nice semantic, pragmatic solution?**

I read my question once more, and I hope it is clear to understand. If not, please post a comment and I will do my best to describe the problem better.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php

Comment: Thx for comment. Yeah, this is a nice function, but: param_arr: The parameters to be passed to the callback, as an INDEXED array. It only use indexed arrays... No key=>value arrays, so the problem still exists, as I don't know the order in which I should add arguments. If it would work with key=>value arrays, I would get You 200 stackoverflow points for this discovery ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kudos for thinking about the maintainer, but I'd argue simplicity is just as important as nice semantics and pragmatism. Consider this: if you had to ask how to write such a pattern, what are the chances that it will be obvious to the reader? I'd much rather come across code where I can just think *"Yep, that's clear"* than *"Oh cool that's a really intricate and clever way of setting array defaults"*.

With this in mind, it seems to me that an array is being used in a situation more suited to a class. You have an id, a label and a name, which surely represents an entity - exactly what classes are for! Classes make it easy to set defaults and provide PHPDoc on each of their properties. You could have a constructor that simply takes one of your existing arrays and [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)s it with an array of defaults. For the reverse conversion, conveniently, casting an object to an array in PHP results in an associative array of its properties.

Comment: Great answer, thx a lot +1. I'm really blind to not see that this is exactly an object. The only thing I'm stuck with is which answer to accept... Would You mind if I will accept mcq8 anser? He is newer here, and give a nice working code example. To be honest I should accept both of them, or none :).

Comment: Good question. I'd [accept the one you actually intend to use](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13396/which-answer-do-i-accept-if-i-have-multiple-correct-answers).

Answer (score 1):

Try to use classes as George Brighton mentioned.

If you can't for some legacy or library constraint, you will have to use reflection. Don't worry too much about the performance of reflection classes, a lot of frameworks use them to do the request routing.
 You can use a function like:

```
function arrayArgument($object, $method, $array)
{
    $arguments = [];
    $reflectionMethod = new ReflectionMethod(get_class($object), $method);
    foreach ($reflectionMethod->getParameters() as $parameter)
    {
        $arguments[] = isset($array[$parameter->name]) ? $array[$parameter->name] : $parameter->getDefaultValue();
    }
    call_user_func_array(array($object, $method), $arguments);
}
```

So you can do

```
$instance = new MyClass();
arrayArgument($instance, 'notArrayArgument', ['name' => 'myname']);
```

Comment: Great code sample, +1 from me. I will decide which answer to accept. Thx for Your time! :).